# Mark files whose name starts by a given prefix

Tags: dired

I'm using Dired+. In `folder1` I have 200 files.
30 files start with `15_02_xxx`, 46 files start with `16_02_xxx` and the rest have other names.

I want to copy from folder `folder1` to `folder2` only files whose names start with `15_02_xxx` or  `16_02_xxx`. So the total number of marked files must be 76.
So how in Dired mode I can select only the desire files?

Emacs 26.1, Windows 10, Dired+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type `% m ^1[5-6]_02_ RET`

`% m` runs the command `dired-mark-files-regexp`, the [regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html#Regexps) matches anything that starts with either `15_02_` or `16_02_`.